# printing smallest integer from user input

Tags: python

I have seen things on how to sort out a list but I am having trouble figuring out how print the smallest number that a user inputs from from a total of 3 numbers that they input.  I have found some answers on here for other languages and I am sure this has been asked before but I have had trouble finding anything that helps this particular assignment.

```
user_input = int(input())
smallest_number = 
print(smallest_number)
```

Comment: You're currently inputting one number. You could start by inputting three numbers.

Comment: _I have had trouble finding anything that helps this particular assignment_ The core of this problem is inputting numbers and comparing them.  You haven't found anything on the internet on how to input numbers, or how to compare numbers?  Really?

Comment: I found a solution I posted below.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = int(input('Enter number: '))
b = int(input('Enter number: '))
c = int(input('Enter number: '))

lst = [a,b,c]
smallest_number = min(lst)
print(smallest_number))
```

Or a shorter way would be

```
smallest_number = min([int(input('Enter Number: ')) for count in range(3)])
print(smallest_number)
```

`min` just returns the smallest number

Input:

```
Enter Number: 4
Enter Number: 5
Enter Number: 7
```

Output

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Found some help elsewhere but let me post what we came up with for other people to read later.

```
print('enter 3 integers')
user_input_1 = int(input())
user_input_2 = int(input())
user_input_3 = int(input())
inputs = [user_input_1, user_input_2, user_input_3]
smallest_number = min(inputs)
print(smallest_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for any number of inputs.

```
list = map(int, input().split())
print(min(list))
```

---

```
Input: 4 2 5
Output: 2

Input: 9 7 5 3 4
Output: 3
```